# How do I check for valid Git branch names?

Tags: python, regex, git, githooks

I'm developing a [`git` `post-receive` hook in Python](https://github.com/alexchamberlain/githooks/blob/master/post-receive.d/jekyll-build). Data is supplied on `stdin` with lines similar to

```
ef4d4037f8568e386629457d4d960915a85da2ae 61a4033ccf9159ae69f951f709d9c987d3c9f580 refs/heads/master
```

The first hash is the old-ref, the second the new-ref and the third column is the reference being updated.

I want to split this into 3 variables, whilst also validating input. **How do I validate the branch name?**

I am currently using the following regular expression

```
^([0-9a-f]{40}) ([0-9a-f]{40}) refs/heads/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$
```

This doesn't accept all possible branch names, as set out by [man git-check-ref-format](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html). For example, it excludes a branch by the name of `build-master`, which is valid.

#### Bonus marks

I actually want to exclude any branch that starts with "build-". Can this be done in the same regex?

#### Tests

Given the great answers below, I wrote some tests, which can be found at
https://github.com/alexchamberlain/githooks/blob/master/miscellaneous/git-branch-re-test.py.

**Status: All the regexes below are failing to compile. This could indicate there's a problem with my script or incompatible syntaxes.**

Comment: I suggest you *don't* use a Regex for it: just use call Git itself in case the rules change some day.

Comment: @CiroSantilli Please provide your "trivial" answer as an answer, and it may be accepted?

Comment: I have created an npm package to clean strings into valid ref names. For people who come across this question in the future, this might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/TheSavior/clean-git-ref

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let's dissect the various rules and build regex parts from them:

1. They can include slash `/` for hierarchical (directory) grouping, but no slash-separated component can begin with a dot `.` or end with the sequence `.lock`.

   ```
    # must not contain /.
    (?!.*/\.)
    # must not end with .lock
    (?<!\.lock)$
   ```
2. They must contain at least one `/`. This enforces the presence of a category like heads/, tags/ etc. but the actual names are not restricted. If the `--allow-onelevel` option is used, this rule is waived.

   ```
    .+/.+  # may get more precise later
   ```
3. They cannot have two consecutive dots `..` anywhere.

   ```
    (?!.*\.\.)
   ```
4. They cannot have ASCII control characters (i.e. bytes whose values are lower than `\040`, or `\177 DEL`), space, tilde `~`, caret `^`, or colon `:` anywhere.

   ```
    [^\000-\037\177 ~^:]+   # pattern for allowed characters
   ```
5. They cannot have question-mark `?`, asterisk `*`, or open bracket `[` anywhere. See the `--refspec-pattern` option below for an exception to this rule.

   ```
    [^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+   # new pattern for allowed characters
   ```
6. They cannot begin or end with a slash `/` or contain multiple consecutive slashes (see the `--normalize` option below for an exception to this rule)

   ```
    ^(?!/)
    (?<!/)$
    (?!.*//)
   ```
7. They cannot end with a dot `.`.

   ```
    (?<!\.)$
   ```
8. They cannot contain a sequence `@{`.

   ```
    (?!.*@\{)
   ```
9. They cannot contain a `\`.

   ```
    (?!.*\\)
   ```

Piecing it all together we arrive at the following monstrosity:

```
^(?!.*/\.)(?!.*\.\.)(?!/)(?!.*//)(?!.*@\{)(?!.*\\)[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+/[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+(?<!\.lock)(?<!/)(?<!\.)$
```

And if you want to exclude those that start with `build-` then just add another lookahead:

```
^(?!build-)(?!.*/\.)(?!.*\.\.)(?!/)(?!.*//)(?!.*@\{)(?!.*\\)[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+/[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+(?<!\.lock)(?<!/)(?<!\.)$
```

This can be optimized a bit as well by conflating a few things that look for common patterns:

```
^(?!@$|build-|/|.*([/.]\.|//|@\{|\\))[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+/[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+(?<!\.lock|[/.])$
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old of a comment, but I was having difficult with your answer. I tried using it in a Linux bash script and there seems to be something fundamentally wrong that I am misunderstanding.

For starters, the space was not working but I found the solution for that using `\s`.

Any ideas on why this still doesn't work:

`^(?!.*/\.)(?!.*\.\.)(?!/)(?!.*//)(?!.*@\{)(?!.*\\)[^\000-\037\177\s~^:?*[]+/[^\000-\037\177\s~^:?*[]+(?<!\.lock)(?<!/)(?<!\.)$`

Comment: @GrenMeera: This probably comes down to what regex features bash (which part of that does regex matching?) even supports. The solution above uses lookahead and lookbehind, which are uncommon to find in ancient tools (pioneered by Perl and available, albeit sometimes with limitations), in many modern regex implementations. You don't necessarily need lookaround if you don't need a _single_ regex that does everything. Considering you are in a bash script, you should probably go with [Ciro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24991376/73070), anyway.

Answer (score 24):

**`git check-ref-format <ref>`** with `subprocess.Popen` is a possibility:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(["git", "check-ref-format", ref])
exit_status = process.wait()
```

Advantages:

- if the algorithm ever changes, the check will update automatically
- you are sure to get it right, which is way harder with a monster Regex

Disadvantages:

- slower because subprocess. But premature optimization is the root of all evil.
- requires Git as a binary dependency. But in the case of a hook it will always be there.

[pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2), which uses C bindings to [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/), would be an even better possibility if `check-ref-format` is exposed there, as it would be faster than `Popen`, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to write monstrosities in Perl.  Just use /x:

```
# RegExp rules based on git-check-ref-format
my $valid_ref_name = qr%
   ^
   (?!
      # begins with
      /|                # (from #6)   cannot begin with /
      # contains
      .*(?:
         [/.]\.|        # (from #1,3) cannot contain /. or ..
         //|            # (from #6)   cannot contain multiple consecutive slashes
         @\{|           # (from #8)   cannot contain a sequence @{
         \\             # (from #9)   cannot contain a \
      )
   )
                        # (from #2)   (waiving this rule; too strict)
   [^\040\177 ~^:?*[]+  # (from #4-5) valid character rules

   # ends with
   (?<!\.lock)          # (from #1)   cannot end with .lock
   (?<![/.])            # (from #6-7) cannot end with / or .
   $
%x;

foreach my $branch (qw(
   master
   .master
   build/master
   ref/HEAD/blah
   /HEAD/blah
   HEAD/blah/
   master.lock
   head/@{block}
   master.
   build//master
   build\master
   build\\master
),
   'master blaster',
) {
   print "$branch --> ".($branch =~ $valid_ref_name)."\n";
}
```

Joey++ for some of the code, though I made some corrections.

Answer (score 3):

If You want to check if reference is valid with [pygit2](https://www.pygit2.org) You can do like that function ([code copied from documentation](https://www.pygit2.org/references.html#functions)):

```
from pygit2 import reference_is_valid_name
reference_is_valid_name("refs/heads/master")
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this question looking for the PCRE regular expression to match a valid Git branch name, it is the following:

```
^(?!/|.*([/.]\.|//|@\{|\\\\))[^\040\177 ~^:?*\[]+(?<!\.lock|[/.])$
```

This is an amended version of the regular expression written by [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey). In this version, however, an oblique is not required (it is for matching `branchName` rather than `refs/heads/branchName`).

Please refer to his correct [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12093994/1470771).
He provides a full breakdown of each part of the regex, and how it relates to each requirement specified on the [`git-check-ref-format(1)` manual pages](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html).

Comment: Thanks. I've used it for my groovy script. Just escape a little to adapt. 
/^(?!\/|.*([\/.]\.|\/\/|@\{|\\\\))[^\040\\177 ~^:?*\[]+(?<!\.lock|[\/.])$/

Answer (score 1):

Taking the rules directly from the linked page, the following regular expression should match only valid branch names in `refs/heads` not starting with "build-":

```
refs/heads/(?!.)(?!build-)((?!\.\.)(?!@{)[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\])+))(?<!\.)(?<!\.lock)
```

This starts with `refs/heads` as yours does.

Then `(?!build-)` checks that the next 6 characters are not `build-` and `(?!.)` checks that the branch does not start with a `.`.

The entire group `(((?!\.\.)(?!@{)[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\])+)` matches the branch name.

`(?!\.\.)` checks that there are no instances of two periods in a row, and `(?!@{)` checks that the branch does not contain `@{`.

Then `[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\]` matches any of the allowed characters by excluding control characters `\cA-\cZ` and all of the rest of the characters that are specifically forbidden.

Finally, `(?<!\.)` makes sure that the branch name did not end with a period and `(?<!.lock)` checks that it did not end with `.\lock`.

This can be extended to similarly match valid branch names in arbitrary folders, you can use

```
(?!.)((?!\.\.)(?!@{)[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\])+))(/(?!.)((?!\.\.)(?!@{)[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\])+)))*?/(?!.)(?!build-)((?!\.\.)(?!@{)[^\cA-\cZ ~^:?*[\\])+))(?<!\.)(?<!\.lock)
```

This applies basically the same rules to each piece of the branch name, but only checks that the last one does not start with `build-`

Comment: Thanks @murgatroid99. Please see edit above. I'm trying to test the regexes, but they aren't compiling atm.

Comment: Are you prefixing the strings containing the regexes with `r` (as in `r"regex"`? You have to do that for regular expressions that contain escape sequences (with `\`) or they will not be correct.

Comment: Thanks... slight improvement... @Joey's first 2 are compiling now, but not yours, nor his third. Yours are reporting unbalanced parenthesis. I'll start investigating.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I fixed the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

I use this for git **branch**:

```
^(?!\.| |-|/)((?!\.\.)(?!.*/\.)(/\*|/\*/)*(?!@\{)[^\~\:\^\\\ \?*\[])+(?<!\.|/)(?<!\.lock)$
```

A Git branch name can not:

- Have a path component that begins with .
- Have a double dot ..
- Have an ASCII control character, ~, ^, : or SP, anywhere
- End with a /
- End with .lock
- Contain a , @{, /.
- They cannot end with a dot .
- ? and [ are not allowed
- - is allowed only if it constitutes an entire path component (eg. foo/* or bar/*/baz), in which case it is interpreted as a wildcard and not as part of the actual ref name