# C# Process Injection

Tags: c#, git, code-injection

In my application I am requesting a tag name and message to run a process to tag a repository. What would be the best way to prevent an injection (if it is vulnerable).

```
string command = "tag -a " + name + " -m \"" + message + "\""; // tag repo
```

Also there is another location where I ask for a branch name to create a new branch in git, does ensuring that is a valid branch name prevent an injection, 
by using regex

```
^(?!@$|build-|/|.*([/.]\.|//|@\{|\\))[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+/[^\000-\037\177 ~^:?*[]+(?<!\.lock|[/.])$
```

from [How do I check for valid Git branch names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093748/how-do-i-check-for-valid-git-branch-names)